# Detect mouse coordinates on hover

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

OK, so basically this is what I want :

- I have an `NSView` (embedded in an `NSSplitView` but that shouldn't matter
- When mouse reach its leftmost edge (or a few pixels more - perferable as a percentage of the overall window width: like *when mouse is within the leftmost 15% of the screen*), an event should be fired
- And then I'm going to expand the leftmost view of the split view

How should I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the NSTrackingArea reference. You can add tracking areas to your view that will respond to mouseEntered: events.